# Python: Finding width from imported css file

Tags: python, css, file

I want to find the number of width occur in the imported CSS file in python.

I'm using file() function

```
    css = open("/Users/john/Work/html/Ribbon/header.css")  
    print(css.read())
    #output

#back {
    width: 680px;
    height: 280px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: url("background.png");
    position: relative;
}

#back ul {
    margin-top: 115px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    width: 476px;
    height: 39px;
    border: 2px solid #b4c5cf;
    background: #f3f8fa;
}

#back #topborder {
    background: url("top_border.png");
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 23px;

}

#back #bottomborder {
    background: url("bottom_border.png");
    width: 100%;
    height: 23px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I'm new to python, please suggest some more method.
Please help me, how to proceed further.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but if you are trying to count the number of `width:` definitions in your CSS file, then you could use the following (very straightforward) method:

```
count = 0
with open('/Users/john/Work/html/Ribbon/header.css', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "width:" in line:
            count+=1
print("Found %d instances of 'width:'." % count)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various CSS parsers out there. Ask Google for "python css parser". Using one of them, I am sure finding/counting relevant attributes will be easy.